# Code returns run time error when going through more than 46 iterations

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote some code that distributes monthly fees between a start date and an end date. It works perfectly fine when I execute it on 46 iterations (this means 48 different subscriptions are calculated). However, after the iteration number 46 it returns a run time error.
Does anyone have an idea how I can make the code more efficient or how I extend the "run time period" in Excel? It would still be fine if the code runs for 1 minute.

Here is my code:

```
Sub CalcualteDistribution()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Worksheets("Table2").Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))
        If Not IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
            Call MonthlyDistribution(c)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

Sub MonthlyDistribution(c As Range)
    Dim FirstDate As Date
    Dim LastDate As Date
    Dim NextDate As Date

    'Amount for months with 30 days
    Dim amount30 As Double

    'Amount for months with 31 days
    Dim amount31 As Double

    'Amount for february
    Dim amountFeb As Double

    Dim price As Double
    Dim numberDays As Integer
    Dim count As Range
    Dim jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec As Double

    jan = 0
    feb = 0
    mar = 0
    apr = 0
    may = 0
    jun = 0
    jul = 0
    aug = 0
    sep = 0
    oct = 0
    nov = 0
    dec = 0

    Set count = c
    FirstDate = count.Value
    LastDate = count.Offset(0, 13).Value
    NextDate = FirstDate
    price = count.Offset(0, 14).Value
    numberDays = count.Offset(0, 17).Value
    amount30 = price / 30
    amount31 = price / 31
    amountFeb = price / 28
    amountFebSchalltjahr = price / 29


    While NextDate <= LastDate
        If Month(NextDate) = 1 Then
            jan = jan + 1
            NextDate = NextDate + 1
        ElseIf Month(NextDate) = 2 Then
            feb = feb + 1
            NextDate = NextDate + 1
        ElseIf Month(NextDate) = 3 Then
            mar = mar + 1
            NextDate = NextDate + 1
        ElseIf Month(NextDate) = 4 Then
            apr = apr + 1
            NextDate = NextDate + 1
        ElseIf Month(NextDate) = 5 Then
            may = may + 1
            NextDate = NextDate + 1
        ElseIf Month(NextDate) = 6 Then
            jun = jun + 1
            NextDate = NextDate + 1
        ElseIf Month(NextDate) = 7 Then
            jul = jul + 1
            NextDate = NextDate + 1
        ElseIf Month(NextDate) = 8 Then
            aug = aug + 1
            NextDate = NextDate + 1
        ElseIf Month(NextDate) = 9 Then
            sep = sep + 1
            NextDate = NextDate + 1
        ElseIf Month(NextDate) = 10 Then
            oct = oct + 1
            NextDate = NextDate + 1
        ElseIf Month(NextDate) = 11 Then
            nov = nov + 1
            NextDate = NextDate + 1
        Else
            dec = dec + 1
            NextDate = NextDate + 1
        End If
    Wend

    count.Offset(0, 1).Value = jan * amount31
    count.Offset(0, 2).Value = feb * amountFeb
    count.Offset(0, 3).Value = mar * amount31
    count.Offset(0, 4).Value = apr * amount30
    count.Offset(0, 5).Value = may * amount31
    count.Offset(0, 6).Value = jun * amount30
    count.Offset(0, 7).Value = jul * amount31
    count.Offset(0, 8).Value = aug * amount31
    count.Offset(0, 9).Value = sep * amount30
    count.Offset(0, 10).Value = oct * amount31
    count.Offset(0, 11).Value = nov * amount30
    count.Offset(0, 12).Value = dec * amount31
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the exact text of the error message?

Comment: And in which line does it happen?

Comment: Careful when declaring variables on the same line. Your line `Dim jan, feb ...` is declaring months jan through nov as `Variant` and only `dec As Double`.

Comment: I tested your code against a mostly empty sheet with the bare minimum of data. It ran without error. Needs more detail to troubleshoot.

Comment: For us to be of help you will want to be more detailed in what is not working, and what is happening when it doesnt work. For example, what line does it error on? What are the values of 'c' when the error happens? Does it error in the sub, or in the loop? There's a lot that could go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This almost certainly *will not* solve the source of the issue with your run-time error. However it *will* significantly improve the quality of your code which could lead to greater efficiency. So this is in response to *"Does anyone have an idea how I can make the code more efficient..."*

```
Sub CalcualteDistribution()
    Dim cell As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table2")
        For Each cell In .Range("C2").Resize(.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row)
            If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                MonthlyDistribution cell
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub

Sub MonthlyDistribution(ByVal InputCell As Range)
    ' Default value of `Double` is 0, so no need to explicitly set the value to 0.
    Dim Months(1 To 12) As Double

    Dim FirstDate As Date
    FirstDate = InputCell.Value

    Dim LastDate As Date
    LastDate = InputCell.Offset(0, 13).Value

    Dim price As Double
    price = InputCell.Offset(0, 14).Value

    ' Use Long over Integer
    'Dim numberDays As Integer
    Dim numberDays As Long
    numberDays = InputCell.Offset(0, 17).Value

    'Amount for months with 30 days
    Dim amount30 As Double
    amount30 = price / 30

    'Amount for months with 31 days
    Dim amount31 As Double
    amount31 = price / 31

    'Amount for february
    Dim amountFeb As Double
    amountFeb = price / 28

    ' Note that you dont actually use this anywhere
    amountFebSchalltjahr = price / 29

    Dim NextDate As Date
    NextDate = FirstDate
    While NextDate <= LastDate
        Months(Month(NextDate)) = Months(Month(NextDate)) + 1
        NextDate = NextDate + 1
    Wend

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 12
        Select Case i
        Case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12
            InputCell.Offset(0, i).Value = Months(i) * amount31
        Case 4, 6, 9, 11
            InputCell.Offset(0, i).Value = Months(i) * amount30
        Case 2
            InputCell.Offset(0, i).Value = Months(i) * amountFeb
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

I only made a few adjustments, but this ideally will make your code easier to read and maintain. The first thing worth pointing out is that I made your variables slightly more descriptive. I changed `c` to `cell` and the `c` of `MonthlyDistribution` to `InputCell`. From there, the code uses `InputCell` instead of creating a copy of the pointer (there's no need). I also removed the deprecated use of `Call`.

When calling a subroutine with an argument just use the following syntax: `SubName arg1, arg2, arg3...`.

When there is a return (e.g functions) you need to use parentheses: `Foo = FunctionName(arg1, arg2, arg3...)`

Instead of creating a month variable for every month (`jan`, `feb`, `mar`, etc) I just used a `Months` array. This makes your code predictable. Note how there's no need for an ugly if/else-if when you are just modifying one value. I have nothing against an `if` statement of course, but I rarely if ever use more than one or two `ElseIf`'s. If I catch myself doing so, I use a `Select Case` or I abstract my code further.

Finally, in writing the values back out I just need a `Select Case` to choose between a 30 day, 31 day, or 28 day rate. Ideally you would be better off with writing a function that handles determining the number of days in a month (since, despite making a variable for leap years you never use it). This is beyond the scope of my answer though.

Ultimately refactoring the code like this **should** make it easier to figure out what is going on, and it should make it easier to maintain the code as well.

Now, whittling away at the source of that error, I would first check this line:

`Worksheets("Table2").Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))` since this relies on the `ActiveWorkbook` as well as the `ActiveSheet` (for the second range call). To resolve these issues, try this instead:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table2")
    For Each cell In .Range("C2").Resize(.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row)
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            MonthlyDistribution cell
        End If
    Next cell
End With
```

Note that now the worksheet is qualified by `ThisWorkbook` (i.e the workbook where the code is running) and the second `Range` reference is qualified by the `With ...` clause. Finally, I explicitly resize the range down to the last row (and this would work with `.End(xlUp)` as well. These measures reduce the likelihood that this is the source of the issue.

This just leaves you with your dates being the source of the issue. Frankly, I havent worked with dates enough to take stabs at it there, but if your dates are causing the issue you either have an implicit date conversion (reading a value into a `Date` variable when it can't be interpreted as such), or you are trying to perform date addition in a way that doesn't work. Without additional detail in your OP, I would be guessing from here.

Take these steps to improve your code and see if you can then suss out the issue. If not, update your answer with some additional detail and we can do what we can to help.

Comment: @Moe No problem at all, best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be VBA?  This can be done with a formula.  In your "Table2" worksheet, in cell D2, use this formula and then copy over to column O and down for as many rows as you have:

```
=IF(AND($C2<DATE(YEAR($C2),COLUMN(A2)+1,1),$P2>=DATE(YEAR($C2),COLUMN(A2),1)),(MIN(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C2),COLUMN(A2),1),0),$P2)-MAX(DATE(YEAR($C2),COLUMN(A2),1),$C2)+1)*($Q2/DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C2),COLUMN(A2),1),0))),"")
```

Or, if it absolutely must be VBA, then this will work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Table2")

    With ws.Range("C2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Offset(, 1).Resize(, 12)
        If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data
        .Formula = "=IF(AND($C2<=DATE(YEAR($C2),COLUMN(A2)+1,1),$P2>=DATE(YEAR($C2),COLUMN(A2),1)),(MIN(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C2),COLUMN(A2),1),0),$P2)-MAX(DATE(YEAR($C2),COLUMN(A2),1),$C2)+1)*($Q2/DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($C2),COLUMN(A2),1),0))),"""")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot!